# Does gyroscope accuracy correlate with sensor delay in Android?

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope, sample-rate

I need very accurate rotation measurements of the gyroscope with at least a sampling rate of 50Hz (the more the better).

This is why I want to know if changing the sample rate of the gyroscope increases/decreases the accuracy of the measurements. E.g. if setting the update rate of the gyroscope lower than [SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST), does this increase the accuracy of the rotation measurements?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the sampling rate of the sensor only impacts the load it imposes on the processor. It won't increase or decrease the accuracy.

[Sensors Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) from Android documentation says:

> The delay that you specify is only a suggested delay. The Android
>   system and other applications can alter this delay. As a best
>   practice, you should specify the largest delay that you can because
>   the system typically uses a smaller delay than the one you specify
>   (that is, you should choose the slowest sampling rate that still meets
>   the needs of your application). Using a larger delay imposes a lower
>   load on the processor and therefore uses less power.

Comment: I have read this documentation; it doesn't really say something about accuracy, but for now I will accept your answer :-)